# Apple like search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need exactly the same search box of apple.com for my website. I tried to grab it but no success. Can anyone help me to create something like that or grab it from apple.com?

http://jsfiddle.net/gHSp2/1/

Comment: Wouldn't that be a copyright issue?! Why don't you try to mimic it instead of just stealing (probably obfuscated) code?

Comment: i just want to know how it works, then I will make my own

Comment: It's not exact (copyright, as mentioned above), but it looks close enough: http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/a_fancy_apple.com-style_search_suggestion.html

Comment: It's apple like suggestions, not search box

Comment: Did you look at the article thoroughly? Look at the demo and view the source. It looks like an 'Apple-like search box' to me. Isn't that what you're asking for?

Comment: DID YOU LOOK AT YOUR DEMO LINK, AT ALL? you think search bar on this page http://qpoit.com/marcofolio_demo/apple_search/ and on apple.com are similiar?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/gHSp2/4/

Comment: @epoch something wrong with css positioning

Comment: i know, just made an adjustment to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what you're looking for
http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/06/css3-search-box-inspired-by-apple-com/

Comment: That article shows the textbox with the weird focus outline. A "outline:none" should be added to the CSS properties.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want:

```
<style>
#search{
    width : 100px;
    background-color:gray;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    border-radius : 15px;
    outline:none;
}
</style>
<input id='search' onfocus='this.style.width="120px";this.style.backgroundColor="white"' onblur='this.style.width="100px";this.style.backgroundColor="gray"'>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PPQYF/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this their's part of code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link id="globalheader-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="http://images.apple.com/global/nav/styles/navigation.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Apple</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var searchSection = 'global';
    var searchCountry = 'us';
</script>
<script src="http://images.apple.com/global/nav/scripts/globalnav.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<nav id="globalheader" class="apple">

    <div id="globalsearch">
        <form action="/search/" method="post" class="search" id="g-search"><div class="sp-label">
            <label for="sp-searchtext">Search</label>
            <input type="text" name="q" id="sp-searchtext" accesskey="s" />
        </div></form>
        <div id="sp-magnify"><div class="magnify-searchmode"></div><div class="magnify"></div></div>
        <div id="sp-results"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript">
    AC.GlobalNav.Instance = new AC.GlobalNav();
</script>
<!-- SiteCatalyst code version: H.8. Copyright 1997-2006 Omniture, Inc. -->

</body>
</html>
```

Use [js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) for theirs [globalnav.js](http://images.apple.com/global/nav/scripts/globalnav.js) and inspect it for

> just want to know how it works